# Is it possible to inject a record with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, record

I have found [plenty](https://youribonnaffe.github.io/java/records/spring/2021/01/10/records-spring-boot.html) of [examples](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-14-records-for-spring-devs#:%7E:text=dependency%20injection) of constructor injection into record types. However, I haven't seen anyone address injecting a record into another class. Is this possible? When I try it I see errors about the class being final. But I'm struggling to make sense of this because I'm not trying to extend it or use AOP, or anything else where I would expect the class to be extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A record is final, so it probably can't be annotated with `@Component` or another similar annotation (although I haven't tried). It can be returned from a bean method that's annotated with `@Bean` though, and that makes it eligible for injection.

```
public record Person (String name, int age) {}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MyBean {

    @Bean
    public Person person() {
        return new Person("John Doe", 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: I took a second look at my code and it seemed like the only significant difference was that my provider method is`@RequestScope`. I dug into the documentation and it looks like it uses subclass proxying to enforce the lifecycle, which is what was throwing the error.